# Corner layout blackberry java sdk 7.0

Tags: layout, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to layout 4 ButtonFields in the corners of the screen:

```
-------------------
|button     button|
|                 |
|                 |
|button     button|
-------------------
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I could call this "easy" but you may have to write your own layout manager which positions the 4 child elements inside it.  The BB layout managers are similar, but not identical to Swing's.  As is usual for BB dev, you may have to play around with it for a while to get it working like you expect :)